# XPath - получение первого общего родителя узлов

Tags: python, xml, парсер, xpath, beautiful-soup

Есть HTML-страница со следующим содержанием:

```html
...

<div class='zxc'>
  <div class='abc'>
  
    <div class='one'>
      <p class='child'>
        <b>Hello, Jack!</b>
      </p>
      <div class='child'>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        <a href='/'>Bye, Kate!</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='two'>
      <p class='child'>
        <b>Hello, Jack!</b>
      </p>
      <div class='child'>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        <a href='/'>Bye, Kate!</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='three'>
      <div class='child1'>
        <div class='child2'>
          <p class='child3'>
            <b class='child4'>Hello, Jack!</b>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='child1'>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        <a href='/'>Bye, Kate!</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

...
```

Из неё при помощи **XPath** я хочу получить родителей элементов, содержащих "**Hello**" и "**Bye**", то есть, `div.one`, `div.two`, но НЕ `div.three` (поскольку один узел выше другого на более чем 2 узла), не `div.abc` и не `div.zxc` (то есть, нужен самый первый родитель).

Прочитал на стаке, что можно использовать

`.//*[contains(text(), 'Hello')]/ancestor::*[.//*[contains(text(), 'Bye')]][1]`,

но он будет работать и для элементов `div.three`, чего бы мне очень не хотелось.
Можно ли как-то ограничить разницу в "высоте" между узлами при поиске?

Comment: у вас `div.three` отработает по `<a href='/'>Bye, Kate!</a>` (поскольку один узел выше другого на более чем 2 узла)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с вопросом, если вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится - буду рад:

```
".//*[contains(text(), 'Hello')]/ancestor-or-self::*[position() <= 3][.//*[contains(text(), 'Bye')]][1]"
```